# How to disable Alt + ` (backtick/grave)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz

I can't find where this shortcut is defined. How can I disable it?

Comment: this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175696/why-isnt-the-alt-shortcut-working-on-my-international-keyboard

Comment: To help googlers: How to disable alt-grave

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Install the [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] package
- The setting can be found in `Desktop`, `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`, `Switcher`
- Change `Key to flip through windows in the switcher` from `disabled` to something else.

And the reason you can not find it: `disabled` means it uses alt+` so it is impossible to find if you did not already know where it is used for ;)

Comment: This isn't working for me with Ubuntu 12.04. I gave it another key. I've ticked the "Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin". I've rebooted. But it doesn't respond to the new key and Alt+~ still functions.

Comment: This does work for me in 14.04 to stop the default window switcher from using alt-grave. But in order to then use alt-grave for something else (the static window switcher) I *also* had to use @codenamejames' answer below.  Thanks!

Comment: (in fact, after using both this answer AND @codenamejames answer, I still couldn't get alt-grave to work as static-switcher prev window. It was still bound to some 'unity switcher prev window on this workspace' action. So I did this answer over again, for *every* action on the unity plugin switcher's tab's list of keybinds. That seems to have nuked it.)

Comment: Run `compizconfig-settings-manager` with `ccsm`.

Comment: Caution: in my settings, this wasn't disabled, but rather, was assigned to a key that was already bound to something else.

Answer (score 34):

This is what worked for me

- Open a terminal and run `dconf-editor`
- Navigate to **org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings**
- Find `['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']`
- Set it to `['disabled']`
- This *should* free up that binding for you to use elsewhere.

(ps: I use alt-grave to switch back one application like you can in mac - works well for me and the setting for that is in dconf-editor under the same place

---

For those of you that don't know what a grave is, it is the key right above the tab key and to the left of the number 1 key it looks like this (<kbd>`</kbd>). It's also known as a backtick and is used in mark down and python as a comment like this

````
`code here`
```or in some markdown dialects, code here```
````

Comment: What is the actual rule called in here>? As I can't find it linked to the commands you are saying

Comment: Anyone managed to sort it out on Ubuntu 16.04? Worked fine for me on 14.04 and also migrated to 16.04 on upgrade, however stopped working on a fresh install

Comment: Did a cross-question at http://superuser.com/questions/1178633/how-to-disable-alt-tilda-on-ubuntu-16-04, if someone wants to earn points.

Comment: Wish I could upvote my own post.... I use this every time I install Linux

Comment: see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077459/966668) for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This fixes a keyboard shortcut conflict with IntelliJ IDEA, as the "VCS Operations Popup" default for GNOME is also Alt+`/ Alt-Backtick

Answer (score 5):

Or as a one-liner:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "[]"
```

Comment: Thanks! For those wondering, this is basically the same answer as the one from @codenamejames but quicker :)