# How can I bind alt-space to open Gnome-Do?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gnome-do

How can I bind alt-space to open Gnome-Do in Ubuntu Precise 12.04?  I disabled the "activate window menu" Unity alt-space shortcut from the keyboard settings, but Gnome-Do still doesn't receive the alt-space shortcut.

Comment: When you find an answer to your own question, answer it in a new answer and mark it as an answer. Don't just edit your question. Read here: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: I tried creating an answer, but the system wouldn't let me answer because I didn't have enough rep or was too soon or something silly.  :(

Comment: In the next version of Do (0.9.1) this should work a *little* bit better - I've got some code that checks that Do can register the keybinding before it accepts it. So there will still be key combinations you can't use, but at least you won't be able to *set* key combinations that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.  I had to disable the Alt-` shortcut

Run compizconfig-settings-manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

Go to `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` => `Switcher` and change `Key to flip through windows in the switcher` to something other than "Default".  (Default means that Alt-` is used)

- [How to disable Alt + `?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132304/how-to-disable-alt-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

OP Posted: Solved this.  I had to disable the Alt-` shortcut

Run compizconfig-settings-manager

[image: Install via the software center]

Then run **ccsm**

Or by terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

Go to `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` => `Switcher` and change `Key to flip through windows in the switcher` to something other than "Default"

- [How to disable Alt + `?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132304/how-to-disable-alt-in-ubuntu-12-04)