# How do I disable system's alt+grave on 14.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys

The solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132304/how-to-disable-alt) does not work.

I'm trying to use alt+grave on ccsm, but Unity's shortcut is taking precedence. How can I disable Unity's version of alt+grave?

Thank you!