# Keyboard shortcut equivalent for OSX Super+Backtick

Tags: shortcut-keys, macosx, migration

In OSX you can hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) and it switches between multiple windows in the same application. Is there an Ubuntu equivalent (currently I'm running stock 16.04)?

And yes, I'm aware I can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to - but that's not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact answer above, another [Ask Ubuntu on how to disable Alt+`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132304/how-to-disable-alt-backtick-grave). I checked my system. It appears that the keybinding to "Key to flip through windows in the switcher" is no longer enabled by default in Ubuntu 16.04.  So to enable it:

1. Install the [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] package
2. Launch `CompizConfig Settings Manager`
3. The setting can be found in `Desktop` (Category), `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`, `Switcher` (Tab)
4. On the line `Key to flip through windows in the switcher` click "Disabled" and set your preferred key combination.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> (<kbd>~</kbd> is the same key as the backtick)