# Disable Control + backtick shortcut?

Tags: 16.04, unity, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I'm currently on 16.04, for some reason there is a shortcut binding (ctrl + backtick) on my system that show system notification but that shortcut doesn't show up under system setting -> keyboard -> shortcuts.

I also check in gconf editor under org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings and didn't find anything there either.

Perhaps relevant to this question is whether an installed program (via apt) is interfering with this shortcut.

I will try to find the offending program w/ xdotool but want to know where else I can check keybinding shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Alt + \`?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132304/how-to-disable-alt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> key is meant for switching windows of the same application (just like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> but only for multiple windows of specific type of application that is currently in focus).

It is set within Compiz settings. In particular , you can install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and unset that shortcut. It is under Unity Plugin -> Switcher , the entry `Key to flip through windows in the Switcher`. It is normally unset , hence defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>， thus you should assign it to something else.

[image]

The fact that it is normally un-set is also the reason why you don't see it in `dconf` settings. You can , however assign it manually. For instance, here is my example:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-next-window  "'<Shift><Control>asciitilde'"
```

Comment: Thanks, even though in my case it was actually disabled and not set.  But your answer was detailed enough that it should be useful to others.

Comment: @AnthonyC yeah, that's what it defaults to. I was trying to explain that in the answer, but I guess my wording wasn't clear enough. Nonetheless, I'm glad I was able to help :)