# Ubuntu 18.04 - Is there a way to disable the alt+½(the button right above tab) shortcut

Tags: gnome, 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>½</kbd> (the button right above tab) for something else, but this hotkey seems to be overriding everything. It is the hotkey for swapping between windows of the same program in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu.

I have looked in the keyboard menu, but I cannot seem to find it anywhere in there...

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the key by changing a setting. Either use dconf-editor, which is not installed by default, or execute a terminal command.

#### Using dconf-editor:

Navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-group`. The default setting is `['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']`. Delete the `<Alt>Above_Tab` key so it becomes `['<Super>Above_Tab']`.

#### Using the terminal:

Execute the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Super>Above_Tab']"
```

You can always reset a setting to the factory default:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that it worked. Thank you very much =)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This fixes a keyboard shortcut conflict with IntelliJ IDEA, as the "VCS Operations Popup" default for GNOME is Alt+`  -- I was tearing my hair out looking for references to PopOS and "Alt+`" - did not realise it was called Above_Tab in dconf-editor.